# How to check username and password with PHP

Tags: php, forms

I've made  two  forms- one for login,  if user is already registrates and the other for registration. User date I  save into date.txt file in this way name:Peter, login:pet123, pass: 12345 | name:John, login:joh123, pass:54321 ect.,I do not use DB yet. 
Here is it

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="user_new" class="user_new">`<br/>

        <label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" required />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password"  required/>
        <input type="image" src="img/singUp.png" name="signUp" />
</form>
```

And the second form for login

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="login" class="login">

        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" required="required" />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required"/>
        <input type="image" src="img/singIn.png" name="signIn" />
        <a href="registration.php" class="custom_link">Registrate Now</a>
</form>
```

And php for login

```
 if (isset($_POST['singIn'])):

        $users = file('date.txt');
        foreach ($users as $key => $value)
        {
            $user = explode('|', $value);
            $use  = explode(',', $user);
            $us    = explode(':', $use);
            unset($us['name'], $us['username'], $us['password']);
        }
        if (!in_array(trim($_POST['username']), $us)) die('There is no user with this username');
endif;
```

But this code does not work? What's a problem? 
The second question, why when I write

```
if(isset($_POST["signUp"])): 

      $name = $_POST["name"]; 
      $uname = $_POST["username"];
      $upass = $_POST["password"];
      $users = fopen("date.txt", "a") or die("Couldn't open date.txt for add record"); 
      $record ="name:".$name . ",username:" .$uname . ",password:" . $upass . "|";     
      fwrite($users,$record) or die ("Couldn't add record");
      fclose($users);
endif;
```

code does not work, but it work without isset. In the second case I get double recordes

Comment: @Mat: Amazingly, PHP actually supports that. Using it is usually wrong, though, and mixing it with code that uses braces is definitely Wrong.

Comment: @duskwuff: wow, discovered something today, thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by "unset($us['name'], $us['username'], $us['password']);" ?

Answer (score 2):

You're not handling your strings and arrays correctly with `explode`. `explode` splits a string and returns an array of component strings, so `$user = explode('|', $value)` generates an array; using `explode` on an *array* of strings (e.g. `explode(',' $user)`) won't work.

What you need to do is introduce nested loops; something like this:

```
foreach ($users as $line)
{
    // Iterate over all the records in the file.
    $records = explode('|', $line);
    foreach ($records as $record)
    {
        // Iterate over all the fields in this record and extract the user's details.
        $fields = explode(',', $record);
        $user = array();
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            list($key, $value) = explode(':', $field);
            $user[$key] = $value;
        }

        // Now check whether this user matches the details in $_POST.
        // ...
    }
}
```

I would suggest, though, that rather than separating records by `|` in your file, you just have one record per line. This would make parsing it much simpler, since `file` would automatically give you an array of all the records in the file (one per line).

Answer (score 2):

You largest issue is spelling. There are multiple instances in this code with 'singIn' or 'signIn' and 'singUp' or 'signUp'. It doesn't matter which you use as long as you always use it the same.

`<input type="image" src="img/singIn.png" name="signIn" />` is your input name="**signIn**".

`if (isset($_POST['singIn'])):` is your post value '**singIn** ', they have to match.

Comment: in both of cases name = 'signIn'